# mysql search child & parent table fields with sequelize in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

In my `Node` application we have used `Sequelize` to connect with `mysql`
Have two table `User` & `UserOption`

`User` table have following fields

```
user_id(pk)
user_email
```

`UserOption` table have following fields

```
option_id(pk)
user_id(fk)
first_name
```

I need to list all user by search text in `user_email` & `first_name`
Is there any option to search both parent & child table fields in `Sequelize`?

**UPDATE**

`User` table

```
user_id  user_email
1          text@text.com
2          anything@anything.com
3          jhon@smthng.com
```

`UserOption` table

```
option_id   user_id  first_name
1             1        jhon
2             2        smith
3             3        david
```

**If I search for "jhon", the result will be both user with id 1 and 2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `include` model `UserOption` in lookup on model `User`. This generates a `JOIN` clause with condition `UserOption.user_id = User.user_id`, as well as adds specified `WHERE` clause to perform text lookup on `user_email` and `first_name` columns of both tables

```js
User.findAll({
    where: {
        user_email: { $like: '%text%' }
    },
    include: [
        {
            model: UserOption,
            where: {
                first_name: { $like: '%text%' }
            },
            attributes: []
        }
    ]
}).then((users) => {
    // result
});
```

**EDIT**

Basing on your updated question, I think that you can try using [`sequelize.literal`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#literalval-sequelizeliteral) method, but, according to the documentation:

> Creates a object representing a literal, i.e. something that will not be escaped.

So it is necessary to escape desired values by yourself

```
let escValue = sequelize.escape(lookupText);

User.findAll({
    where: {
        $or: [
            { email: { $like: '%' + lookupText + '%' },
            { id: { $in: sequelize.literal(`(SELECT uo.user_id FROM user_options uo WHERE uo.first_name LIKE CONCAT('%', ${escValue}, '%'))`) }
        ]
    }
}).then((users) => {
    // result...
});
```

It would generate a query which selects users from `users` table where `email LIKE '%text%'` or where `users.id` is in specified query result.

I am very curious if this satisfies your needs, waiting for feedback.

Comment: I want the results for both user_email & first_name.
ie  if either user_email or first_name match the search criteria,then get results